# scrollTop vs scrollIntoView: why scrollTop didn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using **react** to create a component which needs to be scrolled to the bottom on page load. First I used `scrollTop`

```
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight
```

but no scrolling happened. However following worked

```
element.scrollIntoView(false)
```

Now from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), I understand that setting a high value of `scrollTop` should tell browser to scroll to the bottom and it should be working with all the latest versions of the browsers. Am I wrong in my understanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrollTop` isn't used to move an element or your scroll position. What it does is:

> Get the number of pixels the content of a `<div>` element is scrolled vertically

So for scrolling in your page you need to use `scrollIntoView`, which moves the current view of the page into the element you are currently selecting. If you want to move to the top of that element or do some other behaviors you can check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) about this method.

> The scrollIntoView() method scrolls the specified element into the visible area of the browser window.

Comment: But according to MDN, we can also set the value of scrollTop, in that case what is the browser behavior?

Comment: @RhythmWalia Ok, so it will scroll the element to that position if you assign a number, but it will only work if that element is the one with the scrollbar. if you are trying to assign that in an element inside a `<div>` that has the scroll, it won't do anything. The behavior is weird, but you can test it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_scrollleft2)